# How do I view a command's information?

Tags: command

Correct me if I am wrong:

If I remember correctly, a command in terminal is linked to a specific executable(or maybe a script is also allowed?) in filesystem/disk.

For example, `python` runs python2.7 and `python3` runs python3.

Now the problem is that I install 2 packages with same terminal command.

```
pip install packageA
pip3 install packageA
```

They both has the command `packageACommand run`. So I want to check the current `packageACommand` command infomation to see which python/what environments it's using.

And generally, I am wondering how can I view a command's (meta) information? Like checking what it acutally does/linked behind the scene?

Comment: if you don't specify interpreter when running the command, it will run environment default. To control python version the package is run with, specify it before command or see: http://redsymbol.net/articles/env-and-python-scripts-version/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
which <command>
```

For example:

```
 $ which cat
 /usr/bin/cat
```

Comment: Ah yes it is. I just can't remember. But some commands are binary executables and some are scripts. I can only open and read the scripts files.